# Django queryset with Model method containing another queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-managers

Suppose I have a model, `MyModel`, with a property method that uses another model's queryset.

```
class OtherModel(models.Model)
    ...

class MyModel(models.Model):
    simple_attr = models.CharField('Yada yada')

    @property
    def complex_attr(self):
        list_other_model = OtherModel.objects.all()
        ...
        # Complex algorithm using queryset from 'OtherModel' and simple_attr
        return result
```

This causes my `get_queryset()` method on `MyModel` to query the database to generate the `list_other_model` variable every time for every single row.

Which causes my MyModel `ListView` to generate hundreds of SQL queries. Not efficient.

How can I architect a Manager or get_queryset method to cache the variable `list_other_model` for each row when using `MyModel.objects.all()`?

I hope my question makes sense--I'm on my sixth shot of espresso, and still haven't found a way to reduce the db queries.

Comment: Since this method looks complex, and unique to the instance, you're not going to get around multiple queries per instance, unless you can do a single query, cache it somewhere, and do further operations in python only. 

I recommend instead looking into caching the result of `complex_attr` in a way that can be intelligently invalidated upon changes to `OtherModel`, such as building the cache key for `complex_attr` based on `MyModel`'s instance ID, AND another version number which is incremented by `OtherModel` upon save.

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita Excellent idea. Look at my answer below. I want to refresh `list_other_model` for every view refresh, but not for every row in my result set. Do you think my ModelManager method is accomplishing this? It appears to be. I guess I'll write some tests for it.

Comment: Is there any relation (e.g. `ForeignKey`)  between `MyModel` and `OtherModel`? Or you always have to use `OtherModel.objects.all()` without any filtration?

Comment: @Todor There is, unfortunately, no relation. And I do need the entire OtherModel queryset for the "complex algorithm."

Comment: Well i guess then that what you have posted is a fine solution. Another approach i can think of is to use a function instead of property, so the function can simply ask for the `OtherModel` `queryset`. -> ``def get_complex_attr(self, other_model_queryset):``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it works.

If someone posts a better answer, I'll accept theirs.

```
class OtherModel(models.Model)
    ...

class MyModelManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        self.model.list_other_model = OtherModel.objects.all()
        return super(MyModelManager, self).get_queryset()

class MyModel(models.Model):
    simple_attr = models.CharField('Yada yada')
    list_other_model = None

    objects = MyModelManager()

    @property
    def complex_attr(self):
        ...
        # Complex algorithm using queryset from 'OtherModel' and simple_attr
        return result
```