# How do I make a model automatically from another model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Whenever the user makes a new reservation, I want a profile to be made automatically with the 'first_name', 'last_name' and 'email' fields from the reservation class.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class Reservation(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    check_in = models.DateField()
    check_out = models.DateField()
    num_guest = models.IntegerField()

    reason = (
    ('Birthday', 'Birthday'),
    ('Anniversary', 'Anniversary'),
    ('Get Away From Kids', 'Get Away From Kids'),
    ('Vacation', 'Vacation'),
    ('Treating Myself', 'Treating Myself'),
    ('Leave Blank', 'Leave Blank'),
    )

    opt = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices = reason)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Profile(models.Model):

    guest = models.ForeignKey(Reservation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.guest)

def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=Reservation)
```

I am trying not to modify Reservation class as I need the fields as a ModelForm.

New to coding and appreciate your guidance!

Answer (score 0):

That's what [abstract base classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) are for, I believe. Not sure about consistency, though, but you could still store the foreign key to the Reservation. Alternatively, you could define a @property in Profile and retrieve the data manually (as per this question: [Django queryset with Model method containing another queryset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28598178/django-queryset-with-model-method-containing-another-queryset)).

Comment: abstract base class "does not generate a database table or have a manager, and cannot be instantiated or saved directly." which is opposite of what i need

Comment: Not for the base class itself. You put common fields into the base class and both Reservation and Profile should inherit from it.